# Property-placeholder using envriomental variables as CATALINA_HOME

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I would like to use a Envriomental variable in the location of property-placeholder but I don't get it:

I tried in this way:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/database.properties" order="0"/>
```

but I get this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
>   not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/database.properties]

Also, I don't find documentation about use envriomental variables in the context configuration or property-placeholder.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{ systemProperties['CATALINA_HOME'] }/conf/database.properties"/>
```

If I didn't understand you wrong.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It looks that doesn't translate the expression. Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{systemProperties['CATALINA_HOME']}/conf/database.properties].

Comment: @Josema do you have `CATALINA_HOME` defined somewhere?

Comment: yes, it's an envriomental variable of the linux system. so when I do echo $CATALINA_HOME it's shown

Comment: I used ${catalina.home} and this worked :). When I use your expression {systemProperties['CATALINA_HOME'] it looks to work between <value> tags, because I get a empty string in the error instead of the expression, I think I don't have definied CATLINA_HOME when I execute from eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I used:

and I listened that this work for tomcat 6.0 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way as well, I'm using this in my application

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${env.CATALINA_HOME}/conf/database.properties"/>
```

Comment: You're missing the text, here